# CS0246 The type or namespace name 'WebHelpers' could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I created a new MVC 5 application and copied code for controllers and views from a fully functioning MVC 4 application. After cleaning, when the code starts to step through the /Account/Login view, I get the error:

Line 1
CS0246  The type or namespace name 'WebHelpers' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any assistance would be great. System information is below:

System.Web.Mvc version: 5.2.3
Visual studio version: Community 2015 update 3
.NET framework: 4.6.01055

Comment: CS0246 information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7xf6dxs.aspx. Check if you have missing reference to `WebHelpers` library or you may required to (re)install package which contains corresponding namespace.

Comment: Thanks. That led me to find the link below, and I installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers. However, that package had a dependency on WebMatrix, which was incompatible with MVC5. So in the end I commented out namespace WebHelpers in web.config. https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2